# protocol not returning value

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I am exploring protocol and got a probelem

```
ViewController1.swift

protocol filterApplied {
    func appliedFiiler(isApplied: Bool)
}

class  : UIViewController{
   var delegate : filterApplied?


   // on some button action
    delegate?.appliedFiiler(isApplied: true)
}



ViewController2.swift

class ViewController2 : UIViewController,filterApplied {
         func appliedFiiler(isApplied: Bool) {
        if isApplied{
            filterButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "filter_applied")
        }
    }
}
```

now I know that this will not do anything

as I haven't assigned the delegate to self.

how and where would i Do that so the appliedFilterFunction in 2 swift file is working?

Comment: where did you assign delegate to self e.g. filterApplied.delegate = self in  ViewController2

Comment: You do it where ever one view controller originally instantiated the other. E.g., if in storyboard, you do it in [`prepare(for:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare).

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect delegate to self of ViewController2.

```
 protocol FilterApplied {

     func appliedFiiler(isApplied: Bool)

 }

 Class ViewController1: UIViewController {

     var delegate: FilterApplied?


 @IBaction func onClick() {

    self.delegate?.appliedFiiler(isApplied: true)

  }
```

In Viewcontroller2 you have to connect delegate to self. By either navigating controller or presenting controller.In this case i have connected on presenting controller.

```
 Class ViewController2: UIViewController, FilterApplied {


    func onPresent() {

        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController1") as! ViewController1
        vc.delegate = self
        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

   }


   func appliedFilter(isApplied: Bool) {

        if isApplied{

           filterButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "filter_applied")

        }

   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like this

```
//ViewController1.swift
// definition
protocol FilterApplied: class {
    var filterButton: UIButton! { get set }
    func appliedFilter(isApplied: Bool)
}
// defaults protocol behaviour
extension FilterApplied {
    //
    func appliedFilter(isApplied: Bool) {
        if isApplied{
            filterButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "filter_applied")
        }
    }
}


//ViewController2.swift

class ViewController2: UIViewController, FilterApplied {

    @IBOutlet var filterButton: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            // used defaults
            appliedFilter(isApplied: true)
        }
    }
    // overrides defaults
    func appliedFilter(isApplied: Bool) {

    }
}
```

In the end you can choose to use default behaviour or add a new one.

Comment: And make sure your delegate is weak in case of reference type.

weak var delegate: FilterApplied?

Comment: @AbdulYasin you don't need delegate whatsoever to reach the goal, which I believe is to create a generic solution covered by protocol that assign a filter. what I am saying, the original code does not make much sense to get an advantage of protocol oriented architecture.

Comment: Oh I got it @Vanya. Actually here in your case, you are using Protocol for the delegation design patter (one of many design patterns). But Protocol has it sown significance. As we know that Swift is Protocol Oriented, to better understand it I recommend you start with POP (Protocol Oriented Programming)... Thank You